# Ivy resolve issue rev="1.0.+"

Tags: ant, ivy, resolver

In ivy.xml

```
   <dependency org="abc" name="validation" rev="1.0.+" changing="true" force="false"     conf="build->default"/>
```

in ivy settings:

```
    <chain name="hub-default-chain" returnFirst="true">
    <resolver ref="view-local"/>
    <resolver ref="hub-releases"/>

    </chain>
```

It resolves from hub-releases 1.0.25 but does not resolve 1.0.22 from view-local if nothing is present in hub-releases.I can not understand why it resolves in one repository but not in other.Please help.

Error:

```
    module not found:  abc#validation;1.0.+
    [ivy:cachepath]         ==== view-local: tried
    [ivy:cachepath]          completepath\view-  local\abc\validation\ivy.xml
    [ivy:cachepath]           [working@view-local]
    [ivy:cachepath]           -- artifact   abc#validation;1.0.+!validation.jar:
```

PS: view-local is a filesystem resolver and hub-releases is a url resolver.

This is my filesystem reolver

```
    <filesystem name="view-local"
                cache="view-local-cache"
                validate="true"
                local="${ivy.view-local.default.local}"
                checksums=""
                transactional="false"
                checkmodified="true"
                changingPattern="view-local">
        <ivy pattern="${ivy.view-local.default.repository.root}/${ivy.view-local.default.ivy.pattern}" />
        <artifact pattern="${ivy.view-local.default.repository.root}/${ivy.view-local.default.artifact.pattern}" />
    </filesystem>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your issue may be twofold.

First of all you are enabling the "returnFirst" parameter which would tell the chain resolver to favour one repo over the other:

- http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/chain.html

Secondly I think you need to purge your ivy cache if you are changing the content of the repositories between resolve operations.

- http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cleancache.html

The cache would keep a record of previous resolves in order to optimize network operations.

Comment: I have explicitly set 'returnFirst',because I want the repo to behave that way  and I also tried cleaning the cache manually to remove any entries.Can not understand what I am doing wrong.I suspect it is because of some issue in my resolver.

Comment: I have posted my view-local resolver.Please see if that has any issue